# Network agnostic peer to peer connection on android

Tags: android, ios

I need to either get an actually TCP connection between two android phones or minimally the ability to do a 4 step order dependent protocol  ( A sends to B, B sends to A, A sends to B, B Sends to A) with small payloads (at worst 20kb per message )

This needs to work

- without wifi, bluetooth, or nfc enabled (i.e. over 2/3/4G)
- between Andriod phones and preferably between and Android and IOs as well as between iphones
- Not require a third party server and preferably not require me to run a server

I am perfectly willing to make someone scan a qr code to "pair" the phones or exchange basic identifiers.

Is there anything better that I can do other than setting up my own server and running some network hole punching solution to open up a TCP or UDP stream between the two devices?

If there isn't, whats the best network hole punching solution for android?

What seems not to work:

- Googles [C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/sta) push notification seems to be meant for server to device messaging to trigger a pull.
- [Alljoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org/) seems to do exactly what I want in terms of messaging, except it appears requires users to enable wifi or bluetooth. The idea is to avoid using the cellular modem.
- Android natively supports this for WiFI via [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html) api, but again this is a non starter.
- Finally, there is the [Bump](http://bu.mp/api) api , which does almost everything I want but requires a third party server. This is a no go on privacy grounds since the server learns when people use the app.